# Crystal Report "Load Report Failed"

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports

My question seems to be a repeated one but it's really giving me a hard time.
I have developed an application in C# Version 16.7.6 and my CR report is version 11.
The issue is my application runs like a butter in my computer, which is also a development computer and also it opens the CR but in any other computer my program throws the error "Load Report Failed" while loading the CR. Below is my code for the reference:

```
private void LoadReport()
{
    ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
    try
    {
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "*****";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "*****";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "*****";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "*****";

        MessageBox.Show(Application.StartupPath + @"\Prescription.rpt ");
        cryrpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\Prescription.rpt");

        CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        ParameterFieldDefinitions pfds;
        ParameterFieldDefinition pfd;
        ParameterValues pv = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pdv = new ParameterDiscreteValue
        {
            Value = Form1.PrescriptionNumberForReport    //captures the parameter value
        };
        pfds = cryrpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        pfd = pfds["FROMPRESNO"];
        pv = pfd.CurrentValues;
        pv.Clear();
        pv.Add(pdv);
        pfd.ApplyCurrentValues(pv);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Encountered: " + ex.Message, "Search Prescription", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (cryrpt != null)
        {
            cryrpt.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I will be grateful to receive any suggestions or response to my above problem.

This is the error in detail:

[image: error image]

Comment: Without a [mcve] we may not be able to help you.  1) Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  Sometimes an inner exception or traceback will hint as to the problem.  2) You seem to be hardcoding the user name and password.  Are you sure those are valid on the machines that fail?

Comment: Also there are already many questions for [tag:crystal-reports] containing [Load Report Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[crystal-reports]%20Load%20Report%20Failed%20is%3aq).  Did you check the top-voted questions to see if they apply?

Comment: The program works absolutely fine in my computer how can I trace exception type, message, trace-back and inner exception(s) if any.

Comment: User name and password are correct. Yes, I check many posts regarding the same issue but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: *how can I trace exception type, message, trace-back and inner exception(s) if any.* - well you already do `catch (Exception ex)`, can't you just add `"\n" + ex.ToString()` to the end of the message, for debugging purposes?

Comment: Kindly check the my error image. Thanks.

Comment: @dbc any chances to get the above problem solved?